# how to set maximum password length in web.config file?

Tags: web-config, asp.net-membership

I had set minRequiredPasswordLength,minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters in membership section of web.config file. but i need maximum password length also to set. how to set in web.config file?

Comment: Are you going to use ASP.NET Login Controls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz6e5ezc.aspx) to create the interface or you are planning to build a custom interface based on standard controls for operations like registration/login/password recovery?

Comment: ya i m using ASP.NET Login controls...

Comment: Please see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Password_Recovery.aspx?fid=343748&df=90&mpp=10&noise=5&sort=Position&view=None&fr=11 for an example of custom recovery control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the default implementations of [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) does not support this feature. However, you could obtain the same results by validating the password length when the users set/change it.

Edit related to PasswordRecovery control

If you are using a standard implementation of the MembershipProvider class with the PasswordRecovery control you are unable to interfere with the generation of the new password (more precisely [ResetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx) - "Resets a user's password to a new, automatically generated password").
If you want to use the PasswordRecovery control I see no other option than creating a custom membership provider deriving from the abstract MembershipProvider class or from one of its concrete implementation (like SqlMembershipProvider);

The other option would be to implement your custom password recovery interface as you could still rely on functionality implemented in your MembershipProvider. When the user wants  to reset his password you could use GetUser method to obtain the related information, then ResetPassword to obtain a new password. In this moment you may use the password that ResetPassword returns and call ChangePassword to set a new password that meets your criteria, than email it to the user. There are many ways to implement the corresponding user interface, but the reset password logic would be almost the same.

Also in case you decide that keeping the passwords encrypted instead of hashed meets your requirements, your problem will be solved as users will receive through email their old passwords (that meet the maximum length condition from the moment they were set). For this make the following changes in web.config:

```
      Passwordformat="encrypted"
      Passwordreset="true"
      Passwordretriaval="true"
```

Comment: i m using passwordrecovery control which resets and sends password to the respective user automatically. the password received by the users follows the minimum length but not for the maximum. In this case where can i validate the password length?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `ValidatingPassword` event. Here you can check maximum length, etc. More info available at: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/946218.aspx